# In Java, Type Variables' bounds can only be present in the Type Variable declaration, right?

Tags: java, generics, bounds, type-parameter

Type Variables' bounds can only appear in the declaration of classes, interface, methods and constructors?

Or can I bound a type variable when they are used as type arguments?

**Edit:**
Example:

```
class MyClass<T extends Number> { // T is bounded by the interface Number
    // can a bounded Type Parameter appear anywhere else,
    // besides the Type parameter declaration?
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right - only in the declaration.

Comment: clarify with an example.

Comment: You can, however, bound a wildcard: boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)

Comment: `Type Variables' bounds can only appear in the declaration of classes, interface, methods and constructors?` A little misleading - it isn't about being the declaration of XXX, its about declaring a type variable versus using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.4) seems to agree with you:

> A type variable (§4.4) is an
>   unqualified identifier. Type variables
>   are introduced by generic class
>   declarations (§8.1.2) generic
>   interface declarations (§9.1.2)
>   generic method declarations (§8.4.4)
>   and by generic constructor
>   declarations (§8.8.4).

Comment: But they don't explicitly say if a declared type variable can posteriorly be bounded. But probably not.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this static method:

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(final List<T> orig, final Predicate<T> pred) {
  return new ArrayList<T>() {{
    for (T t : orig) if (pred.allow(t)) add(t);
  }};
}
```

The "value" of "T" is "bound" by each call. Now, it's not really bound at the time the method is invoked; it's "bound" at compile time by inspection of the static particulars of each invocation as it appears elsewhere.

Thus if somewhere I call it like this:

```
final List<Integer> numbers = Whatever.filter(origList, new Predicate<Integer>() {
  public boolean allow(Integer i) {
    return i != null && i.intValue() > 0;
  }
});
```

then "T" is "Integer".

Comment: I'm more interested in "explicit" bounds. :)
But this is a very interesting scenario. +1

Comment: OK, well I'm not sure I know what you mean by "explicit bounds".  I may know the answer, but I'm awful about terminology :-)

Comment: "explicit bounds" probably doesn't exist. But I meant if I can have a type variable followed by "extends `ClassOrInterfaceType`" in any other place other than a class, interface, constructor or method "header".

Comment: Ah - well no, I think you can't; the only other declaration contexts after those you've excepted would be class and local variable declarations, right?

Comment: Local variable declaration? I don't think you can have a type variable + its bounds there.

Comment: Yes yes, I understand that; that's sort-of what I meant :-)  Other than class/interface declarations and method declarations, I don't know what contexts you might be talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Type Bounds are applied in the declaration of Type Variable.

In other words - when Type Variable appears for the first time.

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyItem> { // <- Type declaration

   private T item; // <-  Type usage

   public <K extends T> K getSubitem() {
   //      ^            ^ 
   //  declaration    usage   
     ...
     Arrays.<K>asList(); // <- Type Usage not a type declaration
   } 

}
```